# Using the BingSearchContainer C# class with the search API

Tags: c#, bing-api

I've created an application through which I need to search using Bing. I installed the Bing libraries and after an hour or two searching for instructions on how to use this thing I finally found an example among Microsofts own documents (Amazing! They made such things!). My code looks like this:

```
Uri rootUri = new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/Web/");
BingSearchContainer bingContainer = new BingSearchContainer(rootUri);
bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(AppID, AppID);
var SearchQuery = bingContainer.Web("site:" + domain + " inanchor:" + querystring, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
var SearchResults = SearchQuery.Execute();
```

Running the application generates the following exception

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException' occurred in System.Data.Services.Client.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException' occurred in System.Data.Services.Client.dll
Additional information: An error occurred while processing this request.
```

The break occurs on the line with `bingContainer.Web(...)`
I'm following the example on page 5 in [this example](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!112&app=Word&authkey=!ANNnJQREB0kDC04).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appearently explicitly defining the type for the SearchQuery and SearchResults variables fixed the problem as such:

```
DataServiceQuery<WebResult> SearchQuery = bingContainer.Web("site:" + domain + " inanchor:" + querystring, "en-us", null, null, null, null, null, null);
IEnumerable<WebResult> SearchResults;
```